# Detect if launched process has been closed

Tags: c#, process.start

c# I want to Detect if a launched program has been closed. I am currently launching it with the command

```
 Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Card Downloader.exe");
```

Has anyone got a way of doing this perhaps using a different launcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Process.Start() method returns a Process object.
Assign it to a variable and call WaitForExit() on.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx

```
Process process = Process.Start("notepad");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't include a code example and neither does the given link.

Comment: @Parrotmaster code sample added. Keep in mind this is a 2013 answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `Process.Start` method returns a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) instance. On this instance you could use some of the available methods such as [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) or subscribe to the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event which will be triggered when this process ends.

```
var process = Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Card Downloader.exe"); 
process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
{
    // this will be called when the process exists
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to subscribe to the process Exited event, but also set the EnableRaisingEvents flag to true.

```
var process = Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Card Downloader.exe");
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
{
    ...
};
```

If you don't set the flag, the event is raised only if the process is closed during or before the user has performed a call to the HasExited property, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Setting EnableRaisingEvents to true is a pretty critical bit of information that the other answers are missing. The Exited event just doesn't work without it (at least on my end).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Process.Exit` event

```
var myProcess = new Process();
...
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
myProcess.Start();
```