# How to track closing of browser process opened via winform application?

Tags: winforms

I have winform application and I am opening browser process with some url.
I want to update data on winform application on close of opened browser window.

I tried process.hasExited, but its not working.
Also I am not able to find processid of browser processs in Process.getProcesses.

Comment: Look at this code, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15320871/713789

Comment: You can also try to use the WebBrowser Control. Then you have full control and no unmanaged actions.